# How to add footnote in [standalone]?

Tags: footnotes, standalone

I'm currently creating a script, having my pleasure with the *standalone* format. However I don't get footnotes to work. They would be a huge add-on to my work so far. Let me give you a minimalistic example:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\begin{document}
This is text \footnote[1]{This is a comment} 
\end{document}
```

This won't create a footnote at all. However I was lucky to discover a work-around:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.40, 0.01, 0.01}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{standard jigsaw, opacityback=0,colframe=darkred, boxrule=1pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}
This is text \footnote[1]{This is a comment} 
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately this won't allow me to change the enumeration-symbol. I tried several ways but it seems to be quite resistant. Not that great as working space?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}` should do the trick.

Comment: thanks, that's it

Comment: You can also use minipages, but again it uses a different counter and symbol set.  In fact, i suspect tcolorbox uses a minipage internally.